# How to create a teardrop/water drop filling using css and javascript

Tags: javascript, css

How to create a teardrop/water drop filling using the css and javascript dynamically filling the water.

for example.

[image]

it will fill the water/tear drop depends on the percentage.

example when the percentage is 100% it will full the water/tear drop.

Comment: Consider using SVG instead, it'll be much easier. You can just have a `<path>` for the droplet, and a `<mask>` or `<clipPath>` for the bar.

Comment: Plain old CSS/Javascript is bad at that type of problem - it's not really geared towards irregularly-shaped objects. There are some tricks, but tear-drop shapes are going to be too hard. So you can go one of two ways - generate an SVG dynamically, or if you don't need high precision in the graphic, simply make n images for various levels of the drop. That's often good enough for this type of thing, but it depends on the use case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way to approach the problem is with SVG graphic so create it dynamically

```html
<div class="box">
<svg width="100%" viewbox="0 0 50 42">
  <path class="tear"
        d="M15 6
           Q 15 6, 25 18
           A 12.8 12.8 0 1 1 5 18
           Q 15 6 15 6z" />
</svg>
  </div>
```

The next thing you would want to look at is filling the path with a color based on

```css
.tear {
  fill: red;
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 2PX;
 
  transform-origin: top center;
}
```

```html
    <div class="box">
    <svg width="100%" viewbox="0 0 50 42">
      <path class="tear"
            d="M15 6
               Q 15 6, 25 18
               A 12.8 12.8 0 1 1 5 18
               Q 15 6 15 6z" />
    </svg>
      </div>
```

The last step is to create a create a gradient and with JS manipulate the where the gradient starts and finishes

```js
//change gradient 

function change()
{
let tear = document.getElementById('tear');
tear.setAttribute("fill","url(#grad2)");

}


var click1 =document.getElementById('clickMe');
click1.addEventListener("click",change);
```

```css
.tear {
  
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 2PX;
 
  transform-origin: top center;
}
```

```html
<div id='clickMe'> Click here !</div>

 <div class="box">
<svg width="100%" viewbox="0 0 50 42">
<defs>
    <linearGradient id="grad1" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="100%">
      <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:rgb(255,0,0);stop-opacity:1" />
      <stop offset="50%" style="stop-color:rgb(255,255,255);stop-opacity:1" />
      <stop offset="60%" style="stop-color:rgb(0,0,255);stop-opacity:1" />
    </linearGradient>
    
     <linearGradient id="grad2" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="100%">
      <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:rgb(255,0,0);stop-opacity:1" />
      <stop offset="20%" style="stop-color:rgb(255,255,255);stop-opacity:1" />
      <stop offset="30%" style="stop-color:rgb(0,0,255);stop-opacity:1" />
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>

  <path id="tear" class="tear"
        d="M15 6
           Q 15 6, 25 18
           A 12.8 12.8 0 1 1 5 18
           Q 15 6 15 6z" fill="url(#grad1)"/>
</svg>
  </div>
```

On other examples around the web the guys try to overlay another path but for the easiest approach just use a a couple of gradients with your svg and bit of JS

I trust this helps you